# calling method of a mixin in a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to refactor a front-end to reuse common functions in my component Vue App.
I have created a mixin called `mathMix` as the following:

```js
export default {
    methods:{
        randomRange: function(min,max){
            return Math.round(Math.random()* (+max - +min) + min);
        }
    }
}
```

saved in `math.js`
in my `App.vue` component script:

```
<script>
import mathMix from './components/mixins/math'
export default {
mixins:[mathMix],
computed: {
   rand: function():{
       return this.randomRange(1,10);
   }
}
}
</script>
```

and the error I got:
`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.randomRang is not a function"`

What went wrong here?

Comment: Your error message says `this.randomRang is not a function`. Don't you have a typo there ? `randomRang` instead of `randomRange` ?

Comment: Looks like a typo. And a suggestion for you, don't use mixins. Mixins can soon become hard to maintain. Rather have classes and objects.

Comment: OMG! yes it is!

Comment: thanks guys!
it gets crazy sometimes.

Comment: @AhmedNasr as nobody was interesting in providing a proper answer so that the question can be closed, I did it myself today. You can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mixin has a `randomRange()` method, and the error message says `this.randomRang is not a function"`. The error indicates you have a typo in the call-site of your function.